# Kops Create Cluster fails with gossip in AWS Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I'm following the tutorial in https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md
with a bootstrap EC2 instance with Amazon Linux installed.

And everything seems to be working fine until I need to start configuring the cluster.

This error when running the kops command to create a configuration for the cluster. I couldn`t find any post on how to solve this issue.

Any help?

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-231 ~]$ kops create cluster --zones us-west-2a,us-west-2b,us-west-2c,us-west-2d ${NAME}

I0224 22:43:29.639232    3292 create_cluster.go:496] Inferred --cloud=aws from zone "us-west-2a"

I0224 22:43:29.699503    3292 subnets.go:184] Assigned CIDR 172.20.32.0/19 to subnet us-west-2a

I0224 22:43:29.699582    3292 subnets.go:184] Assigned CIDR 172.20.64.0/19 to subnet us-west-2b

I0224 22:43:29.699632    3292 subnets.go:184] Assigned CIDR 172.20.96.0/19 to subnet us-west-2c

I0224 22:43:29.699677    3292 subnets.go:184] Assigned CIDR 172.20.128.0/19 to subnet us-west-2d



error assigning default machine type for nodes: error finding default machine type: could not find a suitable supported instance type for the instance group "nodes" (type "Node") in region "us-west-2"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is stating you haven't specified an instance type for the EC2 nodes that will act as master and worker nodes.

The following is an example command:

```
  kops create cluster --name=my-cluster.k8s.local \
  --state=s3://kops-state-1234 --zones=eu-west-1a \
  --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.micro
```